# Task just a bit higher on one of the screens than the other

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

So, i've got a dual monitor setup, and until now that i've send a screenshot of both of them, i have never noticed this problem: the task bar is a bit higher on one than the other; and it's bothering me now that i know about it.

I've tried to look around, but seems i can't find an answer. Is there anything i can do?

[[image: Screenshot]
click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyWe3.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The resolution of the right screen is larger than the resolution on the left screen.

Or rather, the resolution on the left screen is not using all the pixels it could use. As a result, there is a small black bar on both the bottom and the top.

If you set the resolution of the left monitor to the native resolution, it should correct the problem.

If it is already on the native resolution, check the refreshrate and see if the monitor has an option to stetch the view.

Comment: The monitor that has the bar a bit higher is a 2k 144hz running at 1080p 144hz. The other was is 1080p 144hz. They are both running at the same resolutin & refresh rate. I've tried having it stretch or change the resolution back and forth for them, but seems it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Are the monitors actually aligned properly? If you go to the control panel, display (or equivilent settings page) move the monitors around until they snap. I think one monitor is positioned a few pixels lower than the other.

Comment: Yea they are allinged properly. Tried it a couple of times and still no luck.

Comment: What happens if you move them out of proportions, save it, and check if that indeed now shows out of proportions, then move it back and save again?

Comment: So i've been moving them around, and seems that only if the Monitor 2 is on the left, the taskbar is offset by around 4 px. If the Monitor 1 is on the left everything is just fine.

It doesn't bother me that much, but not entierly sure what is causing this problem